# BadgeView on a Tab Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm Having a bit of problem with BadgeView in a tab fragment. There are two fragments inside a TabLayout. One of it need a badge on the top of the tab. I tried search in internet for hours. There are libraries but i need to do it myself. so can anyone help me for complete this one.
This is my code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.creativemoments.unipoint.MainActivity;
import com.creativemoments.unipoint.R;
import com.creativemoments.unipoint.notifications.NotificationsFragment;
import com.readystatesoftware.viewbadger.BadgeView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

;

public class TabsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag_layout, container, false);
        // Setting ViewPager for each Tabs
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(1);
        BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, );
        badge.setText("99");
        badge.show();

        return view;

    }


    // Add Fragments to Tabs
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {


        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new LoyalityCardFragment(), "MY CARDS");
        adapter.addFragment(new NotificationsFragment(), "NOTIFICATION");


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

and this is my XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/child_tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```